# How can I completely uninstall my XAML build server so no settings are left behind

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild, xamlbuild

We have upgraded our TFS server Azure DevOps Server 2019.  I am having some issues getting my 2015 XAML build server connected to the new URL.  I need to completely uninstall the 2015 XAML build server so that no settings are left and pre-populated when I restart the install.  Doing an uninstall of Team Foundation Server from Control panel does not seem to do it.  What else do I need to clear out after the uninstall?

Comment: "I am having some issues getting my 2015 XAML build server connected to the new URL". **What** issues?

Comment: Are you trying to reconnect your XAML build agent to Azure DevOps 2019? check here https://blogs.objectsharp.com/post/2019/03/04/Connect-XAML-Build-Controller-to-Azure-DevOps.aspx for info on the url you need to specify.  But XAML build are deprecated and you should move to the new builds.

Comment: I get an error TF31002 when I try to connect with the new URL.  I know that XAML is deprecated.  Out of our 1000 + builds we only have maybe 10 VB6 builds that still run on XAML.